# How to bridge an IP on OS X

Tags: networking, bridge

I am running Virtualbox on OSX with one Ubuntu machine as guest. VB is configured with 2 interfaces. One with DHCP to provide internet access to ubuntu and one as virtual interface to maintain the same fixed IP 192.168.56.104 to ubuntu regardless of wifi or eithernet on mac.

Now I would like access this virtual machine from one other computer on the network (192.168.0.x). Is this possible? Would a bridge be the right setup?

Thank you for any help on this.